# Offset Until An Empty CellIs Found

Tags: vba

I have a column A consisting of various names. I am trying to figure out how to copy the selected item into the first empty cell in column F. This is what I've done so far:

```
Sub CopyFill()
If Range("F3") = Empty Then
    ActiveCell.Copy Range("F3")
ElseIf Range("F3") <> Empty Then
    ActiveCell.Copy Range("F3").Offset(1, 0)
End If
End Sub
```

But the thing is I can't understand how to apply the DoUntil function here in order to keep offsetting until I find an empty cell which the excel will then populate with my current selection.

Thank you very much in advance for your time and attention.

P.S. I am using F3 because this where the column starts for me in this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way to achieve what you want is the following line of code:

```
ActiveCell.Copy Range("F:F").Find(What:="", After:=Range("F3"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

The `.Find` will do exactly what you need.

If you want to do the loop manually (which will be much slower), you can use this code:

```
Sub CopyFill()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("F3")
    While rng.Value  ""
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
    Wend

    ActiveCell.Copy rng

End Sub
```

Instead of `While Condition ... Wend` you can also use `Do While condition ... Loop` or `Do Until Not condition ... Loop`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Peter Albert!